# (Modifying JSFiddle) How do you make dropdown boxes only visible depending on what you selected in a previous dropdown box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is what I'm using as a base: https://jsfiddle.net/patelriki13/m1ezs70o/

But instead, I'm trying to make it so that the dropdowns below the Country Dropdown do not appear UNTIL you select a country. Also, I want to add a third Country option, where if you chose it, the next dropdown boxes would remain hidden.

Any help on achieving this, please?

HTML:

```
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
  <select id="countySel" size="1">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Country --</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <select id="stateSel" size="1">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select State--</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <select id="citySel" size="1">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select City--</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <select id="zipSel" size="1">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Zip--</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var countryStateInfo = {
  "USA": {
    "California": {
      "Los Angeles": ["90001", "90002", "90003", "90004"],
      "San Diego": ["92093", "92101"]
    },
    "Texas": {
      "Dallas": ["75201", "75202"],
      "Austin": ["73301", "73344"]
    }
  },
  "India": {
    "Assam": {
      "Dispur": ["781005"],
      "Guwahati": ["781030", "781030"]
    },
    "Gujarat": {
      "Vadodara": ["390011", "390020"],
      "Surat": ["395006", "395002"]
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  //Get html elements
  var countySel = document.getElementById("countySel");
  var stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel");
  var citySel = document.getElementById("citySel");
  var zipSel = document.getElementById("zipSel");

  //Load countries
  for (var country in countryStateInfo) {
    countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(country, country);
  }

  //County Changed
  countySel.onchange = function() {
    stateSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

    if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
      return; // done

    for (var state in countryStateInfo[this.value]) {
      stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
    }
  }

  //State Changed
  stateSel.onchange = function() {
    citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

    if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
      return; // done

    for (var city in countryStateInfo[countySel.value][this.value]) {
      citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(city, city);
    }
  }

  //City Changed
  citySel.onchange = function() {
    zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

    if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
      return; // done

    var zips = countryStateInfo[countySel.value][stateSel.value][this.value];
    for (var i = 0; i < zips.length; i++) {
      zipSel.options[zipSel.options.length] = new Option(zips[i], zips[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this quickly for you. You can upgrade it and make it more optimized.

You can find some toggle functions added to your code and some lines of codes which are calling them.

```js
var countryStateInfo = {
  "USA": {
    "California": {
      "Los Angeles": ["90001", "90002", "90003", "90004"],
      "San Diego": ["92093", "92101"]
    },
    "Texas": {
      "Dallas": ["75201", "75202"],
      "Austin": ["73301", "73344"]
    }
  },
  "India": {
    "Assam": {
      "Dispur": ["781005"],
      "Guwahati": ["781030", "781030"]
    },
    "Gujarat": {
      "Vadodara": ["390011", "390020"],
      "Surat": ["395006", "395002"]
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  //Get html elements
  var countySel = document.getElementById("countySel");
  var stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel");
  var citySel = document.getElementById("citySel");
  var zipSel = document.getElementById("zipSel");

  //Load countries
  for (var country in countryStateInfo) {
    countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(country, country);
  }

  //County Changed
  countySel.onchange = function() {
    stateSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

    if (this.selectedIndex < 1) {
      toggleState(false);
      return; // done
    }
    toggleState(true);

    for (var state in countryStateInfo[this.value]) {
      stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
    }
  }

  //State Changed
  stateSel.onchange = function() {
    citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

    if (this.selectedIndex < 1) {
      toggleCity(false);
      return; // done
    }
    toggleCity(true);

    for (var city in countryStateInfo[countySel.value][this.value]) {
      citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(city, city);
    }
  }

  //City Changed
  citySel.onchange = function() {
    zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

    if (this.selectedIndex < 1) {
      toggleZip(false);
      return; // done
    }
    toggleZip(true);

    var zips = countryStateInfo[countySel.value][stateSel.value][this.value];
    for (var i = 0; i < zips.length; i++) {
      zipSel.options[zipSel.options.length] = new Option(zips[i], zips[i]);
    }
  }

  function toggleState(show) {
    show = show || false;
    if (show) {
      stateSel.style.display = '';
      return;
    }
    stateSel.style.display = 'none';
    toggleCity(show);
  }

  function toggleCity(show) {
    show = show || false;
    if (show) {
      citySel.style.display = '';
      return;
    }
    citySel.style.display = 'none';
    toggleZip(show);
  }

  function toggleZip(show) {
    show = show || false;
    if (show) {
      zipSel.style.display = '';
      return;
    }
    zipSel.style.display = 'none';
  }

  var event = new Event('change');
  countySel.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
  <select id="countySel" size="1">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Country --</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <select id="stateSel" size="1">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select State--</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <select id="citySel" size="1">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select City--</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <select id="zipSel" size="1">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Zip--</option>
  </select>
</form>
```